# Consulta MySql com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

Estou fazendo uma consulta no *MySql* para retornar a quantidade de pedidos que não foram entregues.

Para ver os que foram entregues eu faço:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT operacional FROM `pedidos` WHERE `status` = 'ENTREGA REALIZADA'");
```

Entretanto, existem alguns pedidos que o status é: *ENTREGA REALIZADA EM 20/10/2017* ou até mesmo *ENTREGA REALIZADA EM 20/11/2017* - ou seja, as datas variam.

E além disso, eu preciso pegar os que não foram entregues. Como posso fazer pra receber apenas os itens que não tem esse texto de "ENTREGA REALIZADA"? Pois este espaço nunca fica em branco, sempre haverá algo como *SAÍDA PRA LISTA* ou *ENTRADA NA UNIDADE*, entre outros...

Existe algo como:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT operacional FROM `pedidos` WHERE `status` != 'ENTREGA REALIZADA'");
```

Comment: SQL ainda está na minha lista para estudos aprofundados, mas fazer algo como `status not like "ENTREGA REALIZADA%`  funcionaria?

Comment: Pessoal, fiz da seguinte forma: criei uma nova coluna no DB, "ativo" sendo ela do tipo INT, se for 0 o php lê e faz a atualização, se for 1 ele pula... funcionou!

Comment: Pedro, sinta-se a vontade em elaborar uma resposta e postá-la aqui como solução. Não é má conduta fazer isso, na verdade, até é bem apoiado desde que bem feito. Leia mais em [Responder sua própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422/responder-sua-pr%C3%B3pria-pergunta).

Comment: O problema do código original na verdade é que uma violação ao [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Você está usando dois dados distintos em uma mesma coluna. A melhor opção seria ter `status` e `data`, dessa forma não teria problema, cada serve para uma coisa e apenas salva uma informação. Como também dito pelo @Alisson Acioli você pode usar campos numéricos (TINYINT) para diminuir o espaço utilizado e tornar o indexes mais eficientes, uma outra opção (talvez não a melhor) é usar o [ENUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html).

Comment: Lembrando que as funções mysql_* estão obsoletas e foram removidas no php 7. Recomenda-se usar mysqli_* ou PDO

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal, vocês me ajudaram bastante, o fato de precisar fazer toda essa complicação é porque as informações vem pro meu banco através de um webservice, só após isso eu consigo manipular... Todos me ajudaram bastante! Forte abraço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado à todos! Confesso que solucionaram meu problema e aprendi uma função que ainda não conhecia.

Para este problema eu resolvi criar uma tabela "Ativo" para saber se o pedido entra ou não na operação (que é receber a atualização de dados):

[image: MySql - Coluna Ativo]

Se for **0** ele recebe a atualização quando a rotina acontecer, se for **1** ele pula este pedido.

Caso o pedido que recebeu as informações tenha como Status -> ENTREGA REALIZADA o ativo muda para **1**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acho que assim fica mais seguro!
Forte abraço e obrigado pelas informações, foram de grande importância!

Answer (score 4):

Amigo uma dica que dou a você é nunca usar texto em campos do tipo `status`. Ao invés disso, você poderia resolver isso de maneira fácil usando o campo `status` como `INT`. Fazendo algo assim:

```
0 = Não Realizado
1 = Entrega Realizada
2 = Saída para Lista
3 = Entrada na únidade
```

E na questão da entrega realizada ter data, você poderia criar mais um campo na tabela chamado (por exemplo) de `data_status` e sempre que o status for **1** você atualiza essa coluna e coloca a data.

Caso queira poderia também criar uma tabela separada só com `status` para consulta, algo com a estrutura assim:

```
id
id_status
nome_status
```

Assim você poderá evitar problemas futuros.

**Com o seu caso acima**

Poderia testar os seguintes comando e ver qual se encaixa melhor:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT operacional FROM `pedidos` WHERE `status` LIKE '%ENTREGA REALIZADA'");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT operacional FROM `pedidos` WHERE `status` LIKE '%ENTREGA REALIZADA%'"); //Talvez dê problemas no futuro caso tenha frases muito parecida no campo status

$result = mysql_query("SELECT operacional FROM `pedidos` WHERE `status` LIKE 'ENTREGA REALIZADA%'");
```

Mas faça como falei no começo do post, é melhor, você evitará problemas e dores de cabeças futuros.

Lembrando como o **Anderson Carlos Woss** citou, use a função **mysqli_** pois todas **mysql_** estão obsoletas nas novas versões do PHP.

Comment: Como [comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202595/consulta-mysql-com-php#comment415152_202595), talvez seja interessante adaptar a solução para `mysqli_*` ou pelo menos colocar o aviso que as funções `mysql_*` estão obsoletas.